# Left join with LINQ Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I'm new to linq so would appreciate your help with getting this left join query to work.

I have "List hours" (a list of hours 0-23) that I'd like to left join with "var hourlyData" (a processed linq query containing aggregated data). My attempt at the left join  is "var reportData".

```
DataSet ds = GetDataSet(sSql);
var stats = ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable();

var hourlyData = from stat in stats
                 group stat by stat.Field<int>("Hour") into g
                 select new
                 {
                     Hour = g.Key,
                     Value = g.Key.ToString(),
                     D1 = g.Sum(stat => stat.Field<int>("D1")),
                     D2 = g.Sum(stat => stat.Field<int>("D2")),
                     D3 = g.Sum(stat => stat.Field<decimal>("D3"))
                 };


List<int> hours = new List<int>();
for (int i = 0; i < 24; i++)
{
    hours.Add(i);
}


var reportData = from hour in hours.AsEnumerable()
                 join stat in hourlyData.AsEnumerable()
                     on hour equals stat.Hour 
                 into sts2
                 from stat2 in sts2.DefaultIfEmpty()
                 select new
                 {
                     Hour = hour,
                     Value = hour,
                     D1 = stat2.D1 != null ? stat2.D1 : 0,
                     D2 = stat2.D2 != null ? stat2.D2 : 0,
                     D3 = stat2.D3 != null ? stat2.D3 : 0
                 };
```

---

The code above produces this error:

Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Source Error:

```
Line 135:                            into sts2
Line 136:                         from stat2 in sts2.DefaultIfEmpty()
Line 137:                         select new
Line 138:                         {
Line 139:                             Hour = hour,
 ...
```

Thanks!

Comment: I'm still getting an error. Maybe this offers more insight: [NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   _Ch.<Page_Load>b__b(<>f__AnonymousType1`2 <>h__TransparentIdentifier0, <>f__AnonymousType0`5 stat2) in 
   System.Linq.<SelectManyIterator>d__31`3.MoveNext() +303
   System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection) +327
   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList(IEnumerable`1 source) +58

Comment: The actual code is throwing an exception in a ToList() call. Is there any code after this?  Also you could strip out all the `AsEnumerable()` calls except for on the datatable for readability and your hours setup could simply be `var hours=Enumerable.Range(0,24)`

Comment: Thanks for your help and the .range shortcut! The simple answer was changing "D1 = stat2.D1 != null ? stat2.D1 : 0,..."  to "D1 = stat2 != null ? stat2.D1 : 0,".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's giving you an NRE because sts2.DefaultIfEmpty() is returning null. In those cases, you will need to make your D1, D2, and D3 assignments in your select statement have sane defaults if null:

```
D1 = stat2 != null ? stat2.D1 : 0,
D2 = stat2 != null ? stat2.D2 : 0,
D3 = stat2 != null ? stat2.D3 : 0,
```

Comment: I did notice that above you have `var hourlyData` but in your join clause you have `join stat in hourlyStats.DefaultIfEmpty()`. Are you using another data set elsewhere?

Comment: "var stats = ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable();" is data pulled from sql db. var hourlyData performs aggregate functions on that stats table.

Comment: Right, but look at your `var reportData = from hour in hours.AsEnumerable()
                 join stat in hourlyStats.AsEnumerable()`. It says `hourlyStats`, not `hourlyData`

Comment: Sorry, thanks for catching that. I modified the variable names before posting my question. That isn't the source of the issue.

Comment: Ah, okay. I'm not sure what else to see there.

Comment: Actually you had the right answer all along!! Checking for null at stat2 instead of stat2.D1 was it! Thx

Answer (score 0):

Since you are doing a left join and stat2 can be null, you'll have to deal with the case where it can be null.

Try

```
select new
{
    Hour = hour,
    Value = hour,
    D1 = stat2 != null ? stat2.D1 : 0,
    D2 = stat2 != null ? stat2.D2 : 0,
    D3 = stat2 != null ? stat2.D3 : 0
};
```

NOTE: `0` might not be appropriate in your case; use what's appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Take a peek at this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336746